# I want to handle the error in response by match

Tags: rust, match

I am receiving a response through the server, and when I am working on the error using match, I get an error during operation, and I do not know how to solve this error. Please help

```js
let host_clint = Client::new();
let response = host_clint
      .post("https://xnbng--80ak6aa92e.com")
      .form(&hashmap)
      .send()?;

let respose_req = match response.json::<USER>(){
      Ok(data) => data,
      Err(err) => {
      println!("Error while receiving response body: {}", err);

      }
};
```

**Error:**

```
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
    --> src\main.rs:268:13
    |
265 |     let respose_req = match response.json::<USER>(){
    |                       ----------------------------------- `match` arms have incompatible types
266 |         Ok(data) => data,
    |                     ---- this is found to be of type `USER`
267 |         Err(err) => {
268 |             println!("Error while receiving response body: {}", err);
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `USER`, found `()`
    |
    = note: this error originates in the macro `println` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Comment: What value do you want `respose_req ` to have when your request fails? Both arms of `match` need to return the same value.

Comment: The value type is USER

Comment: But what if the response json cannot be deserialized into `USER`? Then what do you want `respose_req ` to contain?

Comment: print error messege

Comment: After printing the message, what should `respose_req` contain though? At the moment you are not supplying a value for it on the `Err` branch. If you dont want it to have a value you need to exit out of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use match to assign a value to a variable, you have to return a value of the same type in both match conditions. The Ok condition returns data which is of type user, but the Err condition does only print a line to stdout and does not return a value that can be assigned to response_req.

```
let respose_req = match response.json::<USER>(){
    Ok(data) => data,  // <-- Returns the value from 'data' of type USER
    Err(err) => {
        println!("Error while receiving response body: {}", err); // <-- Returns nothing, just prints a line to the stdout
   }
};
```

So, you have to return some value of the type 'user' in every match condition. But I recommend wrapping it into an option like so:

```
let respose_req: Option<USER> = match response.json::<USER>(){
    Ok(data) => Some(data),  
    Err(err) => {
        println!("Error while receiving response body: {}", err);
        None
   }
};
```

Or you could just handle the error like so:

```
let response_req = response.json::<USER>();
if let Err(err) = response_req {
    println!("Error while receiving response body: {}", err);
    // here you have to prevent your code from further execution by using break or return.
}

// now you can just safely unwrap response_req whenever you use it because the error case is already handled.
response_req.unwrap().DO_SOME_STUFF()
```

Comment: Using `let...else` is better if you intend to diverge. Of course, you can also use a `match`. But using `unwrap()` is a bad idea.